# Change a if-else-construct in a more functional style?

Tags: scala, if-statement, functional-programming, pattern-matching

is it possible to change this if-else-construct in a more functional style of Scala?

```
def getMIMEType(document: String): String = {

  if (document.endsWith(".pdf")) {
    return "application/pdf"
  } else if (document.endsWith(".dxf")) {
    return "application/dxf"
  } else if (document.endsWith(".jpg")) {
    return "image/jpeg"
  } else return "application/octet-stream"
}
```

I tried to use pattern matching, but it doesn't work. So I be curious for a good solution.

Comment: I honestly don't see anything wrong with what you've written. It's not "functional" but Scala doesn't force you to be either, and it's clear what you're doing. On the other hand if you have dozens of these at some point you might want to refactor into something like a Map as one answer suggests.

Comment: I would say the only blatantly imperative construct in your code are the returns. You can just remove them

Comment: Also the else is also not needed. Use if insted of else if. I also see un necessary dots and un necessary brackets in between document.endsWith(), it could be document endsWith ".jpg"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### MIME-Type mapping

I agree with @glowcoder. I find that at least in this particular case it's better to have MIME-Types mapping. Here is a Scala version:

```
val MimeTypesMapping = Map(
  ".pdf" -> "application/pdf",
  ".dxf" -> "application/dxf",
  ".jpg" -> "image/jpeg"
)

def extension(fileName: String) = fileName substring (fileName lastIndexOf ".")

def getMIMEType(document: String) =
  MimeTypesMapping get extension(document) getOrElse "application/octet-stream"
```

Also, as Rex Kerr noted, you can add default value directly to the mapping definition:

```
val MimeTypesMapping = Map(
  ".pdf" -> "application/pdf",
  ".dxf" -> "application/dxf",
  ".jpg" -> "image/jpeg"
) withDefaultValue "application/octet-stream"
```

and then use it like this: `MimeTypesMapping(extension(document))`

#### Pattern Matching

If you don't like first solution, then you can use pattern matching instead:

```
def getMIMEType(document: String) = extension(document) match {
  case ".pdf" => "application/pdf"
  case ".dxf" => "application/dxf"
  case ".jpg" => "image/jpeg"
  case _      => "application/octet-stream"
}
```

Advantage of this solution is that you can can more sophisticated logic in the conditions like for example:

```
def getMIMEType(document: String) = extension(document) match {
  // ...
  case ".jpg" | ".jpeg" => "image/jpeg"
  // ...
}
```

#### Pattern Matching with Custom Extractor

There is also another way to use pattern matching. You can write your own extractor for the file extension an then use it in `match`:

```
object Extension {
  def unapply(fileName: String): Option[String] = {
    val idx = fileName lastIndexOf "."

    if (idx != -1) Some(fileName substring idx) else None
  }
}

def getMIMEType(document: String) = document match {
  case Extension(".pdf") => "application/pdf"
  case Extension(".dxf") => "application/dxf"
  case Extension(".jpg") => "image/jpeg"
  case _                 => "application/octet-stream"
}
```

Comment: Note that you can append `.withDefaultValue("application/octet-stream")` to `MimeTypesMapping` and then just use `MimeTypesMapping(x)` instead of option stuff in `getMIMETypes`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly what scala's built in structures are, but it sounds like you want a map. Like, Java uses

```
val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
map.put(".pdf","application/pdf");
map.put(".dxf","application/dxf");
map.put(".jpg","image/jpeg");
```

Then in your function you use

```
def ext = getExtension(document); // assume this exists, eh?
if(map.containsKey(ext)) return map.get(ext);
return "application/octet-stream";
```

Update: It looks like Scala uses a map that's very similar:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html

Comment: Don't forget, Scala on the JVM has access to all Java's standard libraries; you could use the exact same Java technique if desired, although it is generally recommended that you use Scala libraries instead whenever possible.

Comment: Just so you get the syntax correct, the first line should be val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, String]()

Answer (score 0):

Along with my above comment i would like to optimize it to make it scala in actual.

```
    def getMIMEType(document: String): String = {

        if (document endsWith ".pdf") {
             return "application/pdf"
        } 
        if (document endsWith ".dxf") {
             return "application/dxf"
        } 
        if (document endsWith ".jpg") {
             return "image/jpeg"
        } 
             "application/octet-stream"
    }
```

I See here that the code cannot satisfy any of two conditions at a time. So i would suggest the above code to be used. Also if for the last return statement i.e "application/octet-stream" u can use a proper "if condition", if u figure out the "if" for the last line then all the returns can be removed else the above code is good.

Also the return type need not be mentioned.

```
    def getMIMEType(document: String): String = {}
```

can be written as,

```
    def getMIMEType(document: String) = {}
```

check for this if it works for you.